# Signing Data in Windows Store App for a web service with Capicom

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, windows-store-apps, capicom

I'm working on a Windows Store App. Therefore I have to consume an old ASMX webservice. This service unsigns the data with the Capicom-library.

The problem is, that I can't use Capicom in the Windows Store App.

Is there a way to sign the data inside the Store App without Capicom, so that the webservice with Capicom can unsign it?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: The short answer is yes, but there are limitations. You'll need to find out which signing algorithm the service uses. You also may have some trouble directly importing the certificates, but there are ways around that. What do you mean by 'unsign it'? Do you mean verify the signature? You can do that as well, so long as it is via one of the supported algorithms (of which I doubt Capicom has an unsupported algorithm).